# Bash: Remove line from CSV if conditions met, then remove line from CSV if condition is not met

Tags: bash, csv, text, awk

I hope you're all having a jolly nice day. I have a question which I could do with some help on. I have two `CSV` files, both which contain `250k` records. One looks like this:

```
ProductCode,StockLevel,Active
4101385360060,0,1
6019002320030,0,0
3328200078030,0,0
2411000347030,93,1
```

And the other like this:

```
ProductURL,Product Code,Product Name,More Fields
"http://www.domain.com",4101385360060,Timberland 6 In Buck Boot WHEAT NUBUCK
```

What I want to do with the first file is remove all records which don't need these conditions:

```
<All ok>,<!=0>,<=1>
```

Then with the second file remove all rows which are `NOT` in the first file.

Any help - hugely appreciated. I suspect that `awk` is my friend.

Cheers,

Matt.

Comment: (Thanks for that edit A.M.D - how should I have configured the post?)

Comment: Select the text, <Ctrl+k>.

Comment: Hi, note that the `processing` tag is for the language processing.org - removed already.

Comment: @anubhava, I mean any value is fine in that part. Thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear. For example - `remove all rows which are NOT in the first file`: do you mean not in the first input file or not in the first output file? Are you using some value (field 1?) as a key across both files? Edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input and the associated expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP commented that the id is not the first part of the second file so one way could be:

```
awk -F\, 'NR>1&&$2&&$3==1' file1 |tee -a file1_filtered |while IFS=, read -r id dummy; do 
   echo ",$id,"
done > pattern_file
grep -f pattern_file file2 >file2_filtered
```

Comment: Hey Klashxx, This is amazing. It's gets me to a correctly formatted "file1_filtered" file, but file2_filtered is empty. It could be because file2 itself actually contains multiple columns and looking at it again, the ID we're matching against isn't the first component. Here's an actual line of code from file2:

Comment: Product URL,Product Code,Product Name,Product Style Code,Product Colour Code,Product Colour,Product Size Code,Product Size UK,Product Size EU,Product Now Price,Product Full Selling Price,Product Price Type,Product Cost Price,Product Profit,Product Image 1,Product Image 2,Product Image 3,Product Brand,Product 
"http://www.domain.com/view/product/office_catalog/1,41/410131853600

Comment: @MattRogers Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach (google it and/or see for example one discussion on the subject at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) and you never need grep when you are already using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do. If you edit your question to show the expected output given your sample input we can help you write a brief, simple awk script to do whatever it is you are trying to do. And don't just provide 1 line of file2 in your example - provide lines that should stay as well as be removed.

Comment: Excellent - I've got this code working! Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR && $2!=0 && $3==1{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file1.csv file2.csv
```

However I suggest you to provide more sample data with expected output in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
FNR==1 { out=FILENAME"_out"; valid[$1] }
NR==FNR && ($2!=0) && ($3==1) { valid[$1] }
$1 in valid { print > out }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2

$ cat file1_out
ProductCode,StockLevel,Active
2411000347030,93,1

$ cat file2_out
Product Code,Product Name
```

If not, edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input and the associated expected output.